# How to fix "Permission denied" error when i start namenode in docker ambari

Tags: docker, permission-denied, ambari

I want to install the ambari cluster with docker centos7. The HDFS, yarn and mapred service cannot be started during startup

I've changed the permissions on the file, but it doesn't work

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/common-services/HDFS/2.1.0.2.0/package/scripts/namenode.py", line 361, in <module>
    NameNode().execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/libraries/script/script.py", line 375, in execute
    method(env)
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/common-services/HDFS/2.1.0.2.0/package/scripts/namenode.py", line 99, in start
    upgrade_suspended=params.upgrade_suspended, env=env)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ambari_commons/os_family_impl.py", line 89, in thunk
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/common-services/HDFS/2.1.0.2.0/package/scripts/hdfs_namenode.py", line 175, in namenode
    create_log_dir=True
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/common-services/HDFS/2.1.0.2.0/package/scripts/utils.py", line 276, in service
    Execute(daemon_cmd, not_if=process_id_exists_command, environment=hadoop_env_exports)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/base.py", line 166, in __init__
    self.env.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/environment.py", line 160, in run
    self.run_action(resource, action)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/environment.py", line 124, in run_action
    provider_action()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/providers/system.py", line 262, in action_run
    tries=self.resource.tries, try_sleep=self.resource.try_sleep)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 72, in inner
    result = function(command, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 102, in checked_call
    tries=tries, try_sleep=try_sleep, timeout_kill_strategy=timeout_kill_strategy)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 150, in _call_wrapper
    result = _call(command, **kwargs_copy)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 303, in _call
    raise ExecutionFailed(err_msg, code, out, err)
resource_management.core.exceptions.ExecutionFailed: Execution of 'ambari-sudo.sh su hdfs -l -s /bin/bash -c 'ulimit -c unlimited ;  /usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh --config /usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91/hadoop/conf start namenode'' returned 1. su: cannot open session: Permission denied
```

Comment: Please share docker related details like the Dockerfile & how do you run it?

Comment: ams:x:0:1001::/home/ams:/bin/bash
ambari-qa:x:0:1001::/home/ambari-qa:/bin/bash
hdfs:x:0:1001::/home/hdfs:/bin/bash
yarn:x:0:1001::/home/yarn:/bin/bash
mapred:x:0:1001::/home/mapred:/bin/bash
activity_analyzer:x:0:0::/home/activity_analyzer:/bin/bash

Comment: I changed the permissions of other users to root by changing /etc/passwd